# Slow page transitions on Android with hardware acceleration on

Tags: android, cordova, hardware-acceleration, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run the [ionic-angular-cordova-seed](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-angular-cordova-seed) project on Android 4.3.1 with Cordova. One thing I've noticed is that page transitions (for example, clicking on a tab or a list item) are very slow.

I tried to disable hardware acceleration using:

```
super.appView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

... and it worked perfectly. But then scrolling, side menu sliding and more animations became extremely slow.

I've tried FastClick, it didn't make any difference.

I found this [CSS-based solution](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/) to the problem, but I'm not familiar enough with Ionic to apply it on it. Any ideas?

**Note:** I'm not using any animations for page transitions.

Comment: @Snicolas No, it's not.

Comment: Can I be notified when you get an interesting answer so I could change my mind ?

Comment: @Snicolas Yes... That's what the star on the left is for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Ionic has made a lot of Android-related fixes that really improved performance. In addition, I've splitted my Android version into two versions: 4.4 and pre-4.4. Pre 4.4 is using [cordova-android-chromeview](https://github.com/thedracle/cordova-android-chromeview) which makes it so much faster. Even though it adds ~20 MB to the apk, it worths it.

Comment: According to this thread, chrome-view (on Android 4.4) is actually *slower* than the webview featured in prior Android versions. I can confirm that on my LG G3 (4.4) performance is very bad for this high-end device. The app runs *faster* on an older worse phone, pre 4.4. What's the solution? On 4.4, do I need to package anything special? How do we do this? And on pre-4.4? Thanks! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/1ZxXe6chHZc

Comment: Same issue http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/slow-page-transitions-on-android-with-hardware-acceleration-on/799/13 , maybe you'll find it useful

Comment: IOnic now comes with crosswalk

Comment: @Sani It doesn't come with Crosswalk.  It just plays well with it :)  You still have to use cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: @AndroidNoob At the time of this comment they had thier own implementation so yes. But At the moment now they advice you to use the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Since this bug seems to be very specific to Android 4.4.2 
I believe this may be what we're looking for, or at least helpful:
http://playlablondon.tumblr.com/post/102534909709/improving-performance-on-cordova-powered-android